# Matomo Track event doesn't work when params contains uppercase letters

Tags: matomo

I'm tracking some events from my website. I have a Motomo server with basic configurations, nothing complicated. I'm tracking the events using the javascript API (not the tag manager, I don't have anything in the tag manager, and is not going to be used to track events). I'm able to track without problems except for this case:

this works:

```
_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'add', 'add employee']);
```

if I go to Matomo server webpage to the menu Behavior -> Events -> Events Categories I can see created the category 'add'

this doesn't work:

```
_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Add', 'Add Employee']);
```

Doesn't work means that if I go to Matomo server webpage to the menu Behavior -> Events -> Events Categories is not creating the category 'Add' instead creates a category '-'

This happens every time that the track events category parameter or action parameter has an upper case letter.

Can someone please help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to see the events in the visit log?

I've just tested this and it works as intended. I.e. when running:

```
_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'add', 'add employee']);
```

I see an event tracked with Category "add" and "add employee"
when running:

```
_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Add', 'Add Employee']);
```

I see an event with category "Add" and "Add Employee"

Which version of Matomo are you using? It might help to update to the latest stable version and try again.